# How do I update a CRAN package after submission, if the Windows binary failed to build?

Tags: r, r-package, cran

I submitted a package to CRAN recently, which was a great achievement for me.

Within 48 hours, I found that the Windows binary didn't build correctly due to a mistake on my part. Using rhub, I corrected this and would like the corrected version on CRAN.

I've been reading through the policies:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/policies.html

I upped the version of the package, and re-submitted last month. However, I never heard back from the CRAN volunteers.

What is the procedure for correcting a package with binary build failures? Am I misunderstanding how to correct the package with CRAN?

Any help appreciated

Comment: You can communicate with the CRAN managers but first be sure you incremented the version number. I ran into problems because I didn't realize failing to increment created a collision with the earlier version that was still on CRAN.

Comment: @IRTFM Who are the CRAN managers?

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring why the CRAN submission page is not giving you the answer: https://cran.r-project.org/submit.html

Comment: @IRTFM I've submitted via this UI, and contacted the addresses highlighted. I just want to make sure we are on the same page by "CRAN manager". 

As I say, I think I followed the rules/procedures detailed on that page....and didn't hear back, so that's strange. Therefore, I want to ask this SO question to make sure I'm not misunderstanding something.

Comment: If you haven't heard from them then consider sending an email to the package development mailing list. I doubt that any of the CRAN managers monitor SO.

Comment: @IRTFM Yes, I have tried this. I'm not suggesting they're monitoring SO, I'm asking whether I've misunderstood something about the procedure.